# Infinite dimensional Representations of the Lorenz group

Tags: representation-theory

When we study finite dimesional representations of the Lorenz group we decompose it's lie algebra as
$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3) = \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2).$$
Then a representation of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ is just a direct sum of two representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.
As far as I know the Peter-Weyl Theorem restrics the representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ to finite dimensional representations. So how can there be infinite dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ if every representation decomposes as a representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$? I know there are some like the unitary particle representations. How do they fit in this decomposition?